Python - PPTX How to set table margins
I am working in python to create a script that spits out a powerpoint report. I want to add some tables but the tables that are getting generated are too big with too much wasted space. I've figured out how to manually set the table margins in powerpoint itself but I want a way to have it changed automatically. If you select the table in powerpoint and go to format shape -> text options -> text box then set all the margins to 0. I want to have my script do that atuomatically. I haven't figured out how to do this. Anyone figure this issue out?
I''ve tried this

cell = table_shape.cell(r,c)

text_frame = cell.text_frame

text_frame.margin_left = Pt(0)
text_frame.margin_right = Pt(0)
text_frame.margin_top = Pt(0)
text_frame.margin_bottom = Pt(0)

and nothing in the table changed

The size of the table cell is mainly determined by the row height and column width. Margins only determine the distance of the cell content from the left/right/top/bottom cell edge. See picture:

Margins of the text frame (text body) for text content of table cells have no effect.
Following complete example sets table row height and table column width to minimum and all margins to 0.
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx.util import Pt

prs = Presentation()
slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[5]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(slide_layout)

title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Table"

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(3), Inches(3), Inches(4), Inches(1.5)
shape = slide.shapes.add_table(2, 3, x, y, cx, cy)

table = shape.table

for row in table.rows:
    row.height = Pt(18)
    for cell in row.cells:
        cell.margin_left = Inches(0)
        cell.margin_right = Inches(0)
        cell.margin_top = Inches(0)
        cell.margin_bottom = Inches(0)
        cell.text = 'Test'
        
for col in table.columns:
    col.width = Inches(0.43307087)

prs.save('test.pptx')

Result:

